# Is it possible to save Grease Pencil shapes to the asset browser, then load them back into a different GP object?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am working on a Grease Pencil workflow, and I was wondering if it is possible to save a GP shapes from within a GP object to the Asset Browser, then from the Asset Browser back into a different GP object???

Imagine I have a bunch of drawings for a character, I create a blank GP object, and from the Asset Browser I drag and drop different drawings on different frames as a startup to create an animated sequence, anyone knows if it is possible, and if yes, are there any tutorials on that subject ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Following [this patch](https://developer.blender.org/D13193#438203) and the linked revision which has shipped, it seems support for what you describe has made it.

Comment: Yeah, Matias Mendiola says that it's coming soon in his BCON22 talk! :)